# VBA return Meridiem (AM/PM) from current Date

Tags: vba

`Year(Now)` returns the current Year

`Month(Now)` returns the current Month

`Day(Now)` returns the current Day

`Hour(Now)` returns the current Hour

`Minute(Now)` returns the current Minute

**How do you return AM/PM?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using below

```
Format(Now, "am/pm")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Format(TimeValue(Now), "hh:mm AM/PM").
```

Change AM/PM to am/pm - A/P to a/p. for  lowercase-uppercase display.